# Hard Linear Algebra Problem involving basis of step functions.

Tags: linear-algebra

A net over a closed interval $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite sequence $(a_i)_{0\leq i\leq n+1}$ such that $$0=a_0<a_1<a_2<...<a_n<a_{n+1}=1.$$
A step function on the semi-open interval $[0,1)$ is a map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which there is a net $(a_i)$ over $[0,1]$ and a finte sequence $(b_i)$ such that for all $x\in [a_i,a_{i+1})$ we have that $f(x)=b_i.$ Show that a basis of $E$ is given by the set of functions $e_k:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$e_k(x)=0 \text{ if }0\leq x<k\text{ and }e_k(x)= 1\text{ if }k\leq x< 1.$$

I have shown that given any function $f\in E$ we can write $f$ as a linear combination of the functions $e_k.$ In order to do this we first definte $f_i(x)$ such that $f(x)=f_i(x)$ for all $x\in[a_i,a_{i+1})$ and $f_i(x)=0$ elsewhere. Then $$f_i(x)=f(a_i)(e_{a_i}-e_{a_{i+1}}).$$ Therefore we can write $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}f_i(x).$ This is fine, but how do I show that the vectors $e_k$ are linearly independent? I think I need to consider the sum $$g=\lambda_1e_{k_1}+\lambda_2e_{k_2}+...+\lambda_ne_{k_n}=0$$ where we might assume that $k_1<k_2<k_3...<k_n<  1.$ Then $$g(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $0\leq x<k_1$}  \\
                                   \lambda_1 & \text{if $k_1\leq x<k_2$} \\
...\\
  \lambda_{n} & \text{if $k_{n}\leq x<1$} \\  
  \end{cases}$$

Thus we have that $\lambda_i=0$ for $i=1,2,..,n.$ I am not sure whether this is correct or not and so any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: That is correct, because $g$ is identically $0$ when it is $0$ pointwise. You are evaluating $g$ on $x$ and imposing it is $0$, finding that all the $\lambda_i$'s must be $0$. Fine.